# Is there a way to retrieve metadata (Label) of all Mobile & Lightning Action - Metadata.Operations

Tags: apex, metadata-api, custom-metadata

right now I'm using Metadata calling from Apex.

Apex code:

```
public static List<String> getPageLayoutInfo(Id recordId) {
        String sObjectType = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        String pageLayoutName = getLayoutNameForCurrentUserProfile(recordId, sObjectType);
        string layoutName = String.format('{0}-{1}', new String[]{sObjectType, pageLayoutName});
        List<Metadata.Metadata> layouts = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, new List<String> {layoutName, 'Global-Global Layout'});
        Metadata.Layout layoutMd = (Metadata.Layout)layouts.get(0);

        List<String> actionLs = new List<String>();
        if(layoutMd.platformActionList != null) {
            for(Metadata.PlatformActionListItem lsItem : layoutMd.platformActionList.platformActionListItems) {
                System.Debug(lsItem);
                actionLs.add(mappingNameActiontoLabelAction(lsItem.actionName, sObjectType));
            }
        } else if(layoutMd.quickActionList != null) {
            for(Metadata.QuickActionListItem lsItem : layoutMd.quickActionList.quickActionListItems) {
                System.Debug(lsItem);
                actionLs.add(mappingNameActiontoLabelAction(lsItem.quickActionName, sObjectType));
            }
        } else {
            Metadata.Layout glbLayout = (Metadata.Layout)layouts.get(1);
            for(Metadata.PlatformActionListItem lsItem : glbLayout.platformActionList.platformActionListItems) {
                System.Debug(lsItem);
                actionLs.add(mappingNameActiontoLabelAction(lsItem.actionName, sObjectType));
            }
        }
        System.Debug(actionLs);
        return actionLs;
    }
```

This returns: actionName, actionType, sortOrder, and subtype

I would love to have the "label"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DescribeQuickActionResult Class` to get the quick action label.
Below is code for reference to get the quick action label of the specific object.

```
List<QuickAction.DescribeQuickActionResult> result = 
    QuickAction.DescribeQuickActions(new List<String> {
        'Case.SendEmail'});
for(QuickAction.DescribeQuickActionResult qdr : result){
    system.debug('Action Lable:==> '+qdr.getLabel());
    system.debug('Action Name:==> '+qdr.getName());
    system.debug('Action Icon:==> '+qdr.getIconName());    
}
```

Output:

[image]

For more information, you can follow [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_quickaction_describequickactionresult.htm#apex_QuickAction_DescribeQuickActionResult_getLabel) documentation.

PS.

```
// Called for Account entity.
List<QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult> result1 = 
    QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Account');  

// Called at global level, not entity level.
List<QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult> result2 = 
    QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Global');
for(QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult qdr : result1){
    system.debug('Account Action Lable:==> '+qdr.getLabel());
    system.debug('Account Action Name:==> '+qdr.getName());
    system.debug('Account Action Type:==> '+qdr.getType());    
}

for(QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActionResult qdr : result2){
    system.debug('Global Action Lable:==> '+qdr.getLabel());
    system.debug('Global Action Name:==> '+qdr.getName());
    system.debug('Global Action Type:==> '+qdr.getType());    
}
```

Output:

[image]

For more information, you can follow [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_system_quickaction.htm#apex_QuickAction_QuickAction_describeQuickActions) documentation.

Comment: Hi @Tushar, thank you for your recommendation. I Itried this method but it only return "Quick Action" , it does not have "Platform Action".

Is there anyway to get label of Platform Action?

Comment: May you double check from your side because when I log, I receive "null"

Comment: `SELECT ExternalId, ActionTargetType, ApiName, Category, IconUrl, IconContentType, IconHeight, IconWidth, PrimaryColor, IsGroupDefault, Label, LastModifiedDate, Subtype, SourceEntity, Type FROM PlatformAction WHERE SourceEntity IN ('account', 'contact', 'lead') AND ActionListContext = 'Record'` 
- In this query, you can get the platform action information related to the passed object in the where condition.
For more information, you can refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_platformaction.htm) documentation.

Comment: I have added some of the code to get the label of the quick action and platform action.

Comment: Thsnk you so muchh @Tushar